# If $Ext^v(Ext^j(M,A),A)=0$ for all $v<j$ in a commutative noetherian ring whose weak global dimension is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring of weak global dimension $\mu$. Let $M$ be finitely generated $A-$module and let $Ext^v(Ext^j(M,A),A)=0$ for all $v<j$. Is it true that $M$ has a filtration 
$$M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq \cdots \subseteq M_\mu=M$$

such that for all $0< v\leq \mu$, $\frac{M_v}{M_{v-1}}$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $Ext^{\mu-v}(Ext^{\mu-v}(M,A),A)$?